# AutoIt binary integrity can not be verifed

Tags: autoit

I have a simple AutoIt file, the code of the file is given below

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("File Upload","","Edit1","path\BGD_adm1.prj")
ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Button1")
```

When I was trying to compile the above code into x64 then AutoIt is throwing the following error

**Error: binary integrity cannot be verified**

What is the reason and solution of this problem?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the code. Scan for viruses, reinstall Autoit.

Comment: @Milos "Scan for viruses" What gives you the impression that a virus would cause this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is hard to tell without seeing the program you are trying to automate but using ControlSend might fix it.

```
ControlFocus("File Upload","","Edit1")
ControlSend("File Upload","","Edit1","path\BGD_adm1.prj")
ControlClick("File Upload", "", "Button1")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Windows Defender you should exclude the AutoIt Folder, e.g.

[image: Windows Defender - Add Exclusion]

If you’re using another antivirus tool, it should provide you with similar steps for excluding certain Folders etc.

Comment: Only using Defender. I excluded the folder where the script is located , the %appdata%\local\Autoit\ folder where the TEMP.exe file is created and the program files\Autoit folder. Still always getting an error that the resource %appdata%\local\auto it\aut2exe\temp.exe file could not be created. Also getting this error when disabling Defender Real-Time protection completely. Wtf..

Comment: OK, the ICON I set was the issue (wrong format?), not Defender...